# Why purchase Network Adapter for server instead of using the one built-in?

Tags: networking

Im thinking about building a server and the vendor has the option of adding a Network Adapter in addition to the one built-in? (they're both 1Gbps)

What benefits will I get in terms of performance gains, reliability...?

Comment: This totally depends on the on-board device, the discrete card available to you and the drivers/firmware in use, none of which we could speculate about on ServerFault without additional information.

Answer (score 4):

What if you are a person that needs more than one NIC? Maybe you need 6 ports. That's why you can get additional cards, if you need to attach more than one TP cable to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on a lot of things, including:

- The type of the network adapters already on the motherboard. (e.g. GBit NIC, 10 GBIT, infiniband?)
- The support for the network adapters already on the motherboard. (E.g. no driver yet for your OS?)
- Do you need more network cards than are included on-board?
- Do you need specific features of a card? (e.g. TCP offloading when the on-board NIC does not support it).

Etc etc.